# How is this code assigning subclass object to superclass type?

Tags: java, casting, polymorphism

In the following code, can someone explain to me the meaning of "A ba = (A)b;" and explain to me the outputs and how they are derived.

```
class A {
    public void f(A a) { System.out.println("fa(A)");}
    public void f(B b) { System.out.println("fa(B)");}
}

class B extends A {
    public void f(A a) { System.out.println("fb(A)"); }
    public void f(B b) { System.out.println("fb(B)"); } 
}

public class TypeMeister {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        A ba = (A)b; //please explain

        a.f(a);
        a.f(b);
        b.f(a);
        b.f(b);
        a.f(ba);
        b.f(ba);;
        ba.f(a);
        ba.f(b);
        ba.f(ba);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're casting it to type `A`.

Comment: `A ba = (A)b;` is a type cast. With this, you change a value's static type.

Comment: But, then wouldn't the output of ba.f(a) be fa(A). But, when I print it, I get fb(A)

Comment: No. You only change the STATIC type. Instanc-methods, however, are bound by the dynamic (actual) type at runtime.

Comment: Note that in `A ba = (A)b;` the cast `(A)` is redundant because widening reference conversions are implicitly allowed with assignment. `A ba = b;` would do the same.

Comment: Thanks - I got it!

Comment: Answer in the duplicate link is a bit long-winded, but explains the difference between method selection at compile-time vs method selection at run-time, which is what your question is really about.

Comment: Go through this SO question to understand how casting work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20096297/explicit-type-casting-example-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A ba = (A)b;` Is an explicit type cast operation. `b` is explicitly of type `B`, but implicitly of type `A`, since `B` is a subclass of `A`.

Since `B` is a subclass of `A`, you can initialise object `b` as so:

```
A b = new B();
```

This is equivalent to

```
B b = new B();
A ba = (A)b;
```

...but 1 line shorter.

Comment: That does not answer the acutal question of what `A ba = (A)b;` does.

Comment: @Turing85 I was getting to that. :-)

Comment: *"The compiler would know during compile time that method `f` belongs to class `B`."* This is not actually true because there could be a 3rd class `class C extends B {...}` which overrides the method `f`. Instance methods are always virtual unless they're `private`.

Comment: @Radiodef Oh, I see. Thanks for that info. Have edited my post.